# Passing custom parameter to scrapy request

Tags: python, scrapy

I wanna set a custom parameter in my request so I can retrieve it when I process it in parse_item. This is my code:

```
def start_requests(self):
    yield Request("site_url", meta={'test_meta_key': 'test_meta_value'})

def parse_item(self, response):
    print response.meta
```

parse_item will be called according to the following rules:

```
self.rules = (
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(deny=tuple(self.deny_keywords), allow=tuple(self.client_keywords)), callback='parse_item'),
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(deny=tuple(self.deny_keywords), allow=('', ))),
    )
```

According to [scrapy doc](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Response.meta):

> the Response.meta attribute is propagated along redirects and retries, so you will get the original Request.meta sent from your spider.

But I don't see the custom meta in `parse_item`. Is there anyway to fix this? Is `meta` the right way to go with?

Comment: I don't think `meta` from start requests is propagated in callbacks when you use `CrawlSpider`. But you can use `cb_kwargs` in your `Rule`s (see http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.contrib.spiders.Rule)

Comment: You can also override `CrawlSpider`'s `parse_start_url` to process the response from Requests generated in `start_requests`

Comment: Thanks, what I wanted to do was passing my parameter (like a custom request_id) along with the initiated request, so when it redirected or anything happened to it, my parameter stays with it so in parse_item I would know which request it was.

Comment: I checked `parse_start_url` but it only allows me to process the response, not the request.

Comment: What I wanna do is kind of tracking my initial request. Thats why I want to pass a parameter to my first request and retrieve it from the response. Is there anyway to do?

Comment: You can get the request via `response.request`

Comment: I know, but the problem is the parameter I set in request in the first place is not in `response.request` anymore.

Comment: You could maybe use the `process_request` argument for your `Rules` and add the necessary meta information. And if that's not sufficient, maybe you have to rewrite your own `_requests_to_follow` (https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/contrib/spiders/crawl.py#L57)

Answer (score 2):

When you generate a new `Request`, you need to specify the `callback` function, otherwise it will be passed to the `parse` method of CrawlSpider as default.

I ran into a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25530998/scrapy-deploy-doesnt-match-debug-result) and it took me a while to debug.

> callback (callable) – the function that will be called with the response of this request (once its downloaded) as its first parameter. For more information see Passing additional data to callback functions below. If a Request doesn’t specify a callback, the spider’s parse() method will be used. Note that if exceptions are raised during processing, errback is called instead.
>
> method (string) – the HTTP method of this request. Defaults to 'GET'.
>
> meta (dict) – the initial values for the Request.meta attribute. If given, the dict passed in this parameter will be shallow copied.

Answer (score 0):

To pass an extra parameter you must use
`cb_kwargs`, then call the parameter in the parse method.

You can refer to [this part](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#passing-additional-data-to-callback-functions) of the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want is `response.meta['test_meta_key']`. That's the way to access meta parameters.